# Identify <br> tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to walk down a sibling structure of `<a>` tags and there are `<br>` tags inbetween. When I try to get elem.name of a `br` tag, I get an error. Is there a way to skip these `br` tags?

Currently, I do `html = html.replace('<br>','\n')` before parsing, but that causes bsoup to insert ^M characters with the newlines.

```
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # page = r.text.replace('<br>','\n')
    soup = bsoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    soup = soup.find('div', id='listAlbum')
    albums = soup.find_all('div', class_='album')
    for album in albums:
            name = album.text.replace('"','').replace(':','').rstrip()
            print(name)
            albumtask(name)
            song = album.next_sibling
            while song.name != 'div' and song.name != 'script':
                    if song.name != 'a' or song.get('id'):
                            song = song.next_sibling
                            continue
                    t = threading.Thread(target=tsong, args=(song,))
                    t.start()
                    song = song.next_sibling
                    while song.is_empty_element:
                            song = song.next_sibling
                    time.sleep(0.2)
```

```
<div id="listAlbum">
<a id="1545"></a><div class="album">album: <b>"Pablo Honey"</b> (1993)<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&amp;keywords=RADIOHEAD+Pablo+Honey&amp;tag=azlyricsunive-20&amp;index=music&amp;linkCode=ur2&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=9325" rel="external"><img width="30" height="18" src="http://images.azlyrics.com/amn.png" alt="buy this CD or download MP3s at amazon.com!"></a></span></div>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/you.html" target="_blank">You</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/creep.html" target="_blank">Creep</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/howdoyou.html" target="_blank">How Do You?</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/stopwhispering.html" target="_blank">Stop Whispering</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/thinkingaboutyou.html" target="_blank">Thinking About You</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/anyonecanplayguitar.html" target="_blank">Anyone Can Play Guitar</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/ripcord.html" target="_blank">Ripcord</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/vegetable.html" target="_blank">Vegetable</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/proveyourself.html" target="_blank">Prove Yourself</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/icant.html" target="_blank">I Can't</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/lurgee.html" target="_blank">Lurgee</a><br>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/blowout.html" target="_blank">Blow Out</a><br>

<a id="1543"></a><div class="album">EP: <b>"My Iron Lung"</b> (1994)<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&amp;keywords=RADIOHEAD+My+Iron+Lung&amp;tag=azlyricsunive-20&amp;index=music&amp;linkCode=ur2&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=9325" rel="external"><img width="30" height="18" src="http://images.azlyrics.com/amn.png" alt="buy this CD or download MP3s at amazon.com!"></a></span></div>
<a href="../lyrics/radiohead/myironlung.html" target="_blank">My Iron Lung</a><br>
```

And it continues like that.

Comment: Slightly off topic (and I know nothing of Python or Beautiful Soup) but in HTML terms, perhaps a good time to remove the <br>'s and move to using CSS to create spacing / padding / margins between elements (or using "display:block" for your <a>'s). Using line breaks for display purposes is done better with CSS used for display purposes.

Comment: Okay. It's not my HTML in this case though.

Comment: @user193661 could you provide a sample input HTML and the desired output for this sample? Would really help to help.

Comment: @alecxe Updated it

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate over every album first - these are the elements matching the `#listAlbum .album` CSS selector. Now, for every album, [find all `a` following siblings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) and iterate over them collecting song titles. When encounter an element with an `id`, break. Implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div id="listAlbum">
    <a id="1545"></a><div class="album">album: <b>"Pablo Honey"</b> (1993)<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&amp;keywords=RADIOHEAD+Pablo+Honey&amp;tag=azlyricsunive-20&amp;index=music&amp;linkCode=ur2&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=9325" rel="external"><img width="30" height="18" src="http://images.azlyrics.com/amn.png" alt="buy this CD or download MP3s at amazon.com!"></a></span></div>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/you.html" target="_blank">You</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/creep.html" target="_blank">Creep</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/howdoyou.html" target="_blank">How Do You?</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/stopwhispering.html" target="_blank">Stop Whispering</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/thinkingaboutyou.html" target="_blank">Thinking About You</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/anyonecanplayguitar.html" target="_blank">Anyone Can Play Guitar</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/ripcord.html" target="_blank">Ripcord</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/vegetable.html" target="_blank">Vegetable</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/proveyourself.html" target="_blank">Prove Yourself</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/icant.html" target="_blank">I Can't</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/lurgee.html" target="_blank">Lurgee</a><br>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/blowout.html" target="_blank">Blow Out</a><br>

    <a id="1543"></a><div class="album">EP: <b>"My Iron Lung"</b> (1994)<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?ie=UTF8&amp;keywords=RADIOHEAD+My+Iron+Lung&amp;tag=azlyricsunive-20&amp;index=music&amp;linkCode=ur2&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=9325" rel="external"><img width="30" height="18" src="http://images.azlyrics.com/amn.png" alt="buy this CD or download MP3s at amazon.com!"></a></span></div>
    <a href="../lyrics/radiohead/myironlung.html" target="_blank">My Iron Lung</a><br>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")
albums = defaultdict(list)
for album in soup.select("#listAlbum .album"):
    album_title = album.get_text().strip()
    for song in album.find_next_siblings("a"):
        if "id" in song.attrs:
            break

        song_title = song.get_text(strip=True)
        albums[album_title].append(song_title)

pprint(dict(albums))
```

Prints:

```
{'EP: "My Iron Lung" (1994)': ['My Iron Lung'],
 'album: "Pablo Honey" (1993)': ['You',
                                 'Creep',
                                 'How Do You?',
                                 'Stop Whispering',
                                 'Thinking About You',
                                 'Anyone Can Play Guitar',
                                 'Ripcord',
                                 'Vegetable',
                                 'Prove Yourself',
                                 "I Can't",
                                 'Lurgee',
                                 'Blow Out']}
```